# How to allow non-admin users to authenticate via OAuth2.0 for tenants where users are not allowed to consent apps on their behalf?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

We have an app that uses Office365 OAuth to register and authenticate users (via the `allauth.social` Django library).

The problem is, when the Microsoft/Azure tenant is configured to restrict non-admin users from "consent[ing] to apps accessing company data on their behalf", users are not able to register and login.

We have tried to grant admin consent either via `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_name}/adminconsent` and `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_name}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?prompt=admin_consent`. And although our admin users are able to successfully register and grant the permissions (and also able to retrieve tokens that can be used to impersonate as any user in the tenant), individual users are still not able to register/login to our app, since they are not allowed to complete the OAuth flow. They are just met with the following page: [image]

How do we allow non-admin users to login with OAuth when they are restricted from doing so?

P.S. we are using the Microsoft Graph API

Comment: Not 100% sure I understand the issue, but sounds similar to something I ran into and fixed by going to the AAD app settings page and under Required Permissions > Delegated Permissions, check Sign In and Read User Profile, followed by a Grant Permissions

Comment: Unfortunately applications registered via the Azure portal do not work with the Graph API. They need to be registered through https://apps.dev.microsoft.com. I couldn't find a way to manually Grant Permissions for installed apps created via `apps.dev` as well.

Comment: @john2x that's not the case. Apps registered in the Azure Portal can absolutely call the Microsoft Graph API.  apps.dev is for registering v2 applications (apps that use the converged endpoints that can sign in Azure AD and Microsoft accounts) whereas the azure portal registers v1 applications (apps that can only sign in Azure AD accounts). [Screenshot of Azure Portal w/ Microsoft Graph](http://imgur.com/a/WCiMp).

Comment: @john2x Can you please specify the exact permissions you are requesting in your application?

Comment: @NavyaCanumalla permissions for this app are `Calendars.ReadWrite`, `Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared`, `Contacts.ReadWrite`, `Mail.ReadWrite`, `Mail.Send`, `offline_access`, `openid`, `profile`, `User.Read` (http://imgur.com/a/W9A4v)

Comment: @DanielDobalian that doesn't seem to be the case in practice. We tried using an application registered in Azure Portal. We had to use the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize` (non `v2`) url to authorize. Then the access token retrieved from the non-v2 `token` url returns a 401 response when used on a Graph API endpoint (e.g. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`).

Comment: The error message for the 401 response from the last comment is `InvalidAuthenticationToken: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: -2147184118`.

Comment: @john2x you can get that error only if you are getting an access token for a MSA user through the v2 endpoint, given that it is the only way you can get a compact token today. When you use an MSA with the non-v2 endpoint, you already get a JWT (as you are in fact getting an Azure AD token, not an MSA one). Can you try to get a token using a "native" Azure AD user instead, like alias@something.onmicrosoft.com?

Comment: Also, about your permissions: from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference, "Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared are only valid for work or school accounts". Even more so, I'd recommend to try the flow with an Azure AD account (as opposed to a MSA)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you might still need to do admin consent for the app itself (the URLs you share in your question don't include the app ID).  You can try doing admin consent for the app using a URL like this one: `https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={0}&resource={1}&redirect_uri={2}&prompt=admin_consent` where:

- {0} = your client ID
- {1} = the scope you want to grant permission to
- {2} = a redirect URI (note: for just forcing admin consent this technically doesn't have to exist because by the time we redirect to it the consent has already happened)

Once you've had an admin consent to the app itself, individual users should be able to log in without needing to go through any consent flows.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. Did not notice the different url (`login.windows.net`). Is this authorize url documented elsewhere? Is it different from `login.microsoftonline.com`? I've had no luck finding references to it. I think it would be good to have a link to some official documentation about it.

Comment: To clarify, the `resource` parameter needs to be set to `https://graph.microsoft.com`. And also, once admin consent has been granted, make sure to **not** specify `prompt=consent` when authorizing non-admin users, otherwise they'll always get the page to consent, which will still fail even after admin consent.